# File In Use error in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I currently have an SSIS package which runs a foreach loop around a folder and stores rows from in a number of Excel worksheets into a database. This works just fine.

Outside the loop, I then have a foreach loop which follows to move the processed files into another folder. When it reaches this point, I get an error of

> The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another
>   process.

I've tried putting in a 10 second delay step, but that still isn't helping. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the lock hasn't been released. You could try something like this: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/01/custom-ssis-component-file-in-use-task.html

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like you should have to do this, but you can adjust the maximum concurrent executables and threads.  May help, but will also reduce performance.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlperf/archive/2007/05/11/implement-parallel-execution-in-ssis.aspx

Comment: Thanks Sam. The answer actually seems to be a little stranger. If I also have explorer open on the directory, it thinks it is locked. If not, it works.